# how to use jquery to prevent the others type?

Tags: jquery

html structure:

```
 1,  <input id="edit-field-14sq-und-0-value" name="field_14sq[und][0][value]" value="" size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text"></div>


2,  <input id="edit-field-15sq-und-0-value" name="field_14sq[und][0][value]" value="" size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text"></div>


3 , <input id="edit-field-16sq-und-0-value" name="field_14sq[und][0][value]" value="" size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text"></div>


4 ,<input id="edit-field-17sq-und-0-value" name="field_14sq[und][0][value]" value="" size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text"></div>


5 ,<input id="edit-field-18sq-und-0-value" name="field_14sq[und][0][value]" value="" size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text"></div>
```

now, i want to do, if the 1, 2, 3, input box  has value, then can't type anything in 4, 5.

if the 4, 5, input box  has value. then can't type anything in 1, 2, 3.

the following is my test code. but it can't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#edit-field-14sq-und-0-value').keyup(function() {
    if ($('#edit-field-16sq-und-0-value').val().length > 0) {
        alert('you can\'t type them at the same time');
        $(this).val('');
        $("#edit-field-15sq-und-0-value").val('');
    }
})

});
```

the keyup function is give an error under firebug.

Edit: added "\" to escape single quote in alert();

Comment: You should - no matter what - escape the second `'` in your alert.. This may be what is causing you trouble..

Comment: If that code is copy/paste, you have an un-escaped apostrophe in your alert:  `alert('you can\'t type them at the same time');`

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6041779/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 2):

change this line `alert('you can't type them at the same time');` to

`alert('you can\'t type them at the same time');`

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/x64dH/1/

HTML:

```
1,  <input id="edit-field-14sq-und-0-value" name="field_14sq[und][0][value]" value="" size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text form-text-1" type="text"><br />


2,  <input id="edit-field-15sq-und-0-value" name="field_14sq[und][0][value]" value="" size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text form-text-1" type="text"><br />


3, <input id="edit-field-16sq-und-0-value" name="field_14sq[und][0][value]" value="" size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text form-text-1" type="text"><br />


4, <input id="edit-field-17sq-und-0-value" name="field_14sq[und][0][value]" value="" size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text form-text-2" type="text"><br />


5, <input id="edit-field-18sq-und-0-value" name="field_14sq[und][0][value]" value="" size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text form-text-2" type="text">
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.form-text-1').keyup(function() {
        $('.form-text-2').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.form-text-1').each(function(index){
            if ($(this).val() != ''){
                $('.form-text-2').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        });
    })

    $('.form-text-2').keyup(function() {
        $('.form-text-1').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.form-text-2').each(function(index){
            if ($(this).val() != ''){
                $('.form-text-1').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Would like to add that using `.prop('disabled',false)` `.prop('disabled',true)` would be the correct usage, even though the latest jquery 1.6.1 patch amended this particular special case: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/

Comment: Using this function generates a Firebug warning using Firefox  and Firebug 

The error:
"The ‘charCode’ property of a keyup event should not be used. The value is meaningless."

Comment: i can't understand this well.$('.form-text-1').each(function(index){
            if ($(this).val() != ''){
                $('.form-text-2').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }  could you explain it for me. thank you.

Comment: It means system will go through the elements have class = 'form-text-1' and check their values. If their values is not blank, then disable the elements have class = 'form-text-2'

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#form1, #form2, #form3, #form4").change(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('value')!=''){
    $("#form5, #form6, #form7, #form8,#form9, #form10, #form11").attr('readonly','readonly');
  } else {
    $("#form5, #form6, #form7, #form8,#form9, #form10, #form11").removeAttr('readonly');
  }
});
```

and so on with the other combinations

Comment: i am sorry it's says"TypeError:$("#form1, #form2, #form3, #form4") is null"

Comment: that's weird, as it works for me. Is your markup standards compliant?

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
jQuery("#form1").keyup(function () {
   if(jQuery("#form1").val() != "" && jQuery("#form2").val() != ""){
       jQuery("#form3").attr("disabled","disabled");
   }
});
```

and repeat this for all forms.