# is there a simple a way to prevent the other input can type in jquery?

Tags: jquery

the html structure:

```
1,  <input id="form1" size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text">

2,  <input id="form2" size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text">

3,  <input id="form3"  size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text">

4,  <input id="form4"  size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text">

5,  <input id="form5"  size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text">

6,  <input id="form6" size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text">

7,  <input id="form7"  size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text">

8,  <input id="form8"  size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text">

9,  <input id="form9"  size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text">

10,  <input id="form10"  size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text">

11,  <input id="form11"  size="12" maxlength="10" class="form-text" type="text">
```

if don't alter the html structure. is there a way to do this.

if 1,2,3,4 have content. then the rest can't type anything.

if 4,5,6 have something. then the rest can't type anything.

if 8 has something.then the rest can't type anything.

if  9,10,11 has something.then the rest can't type anything.

Comment: Whats wrong with the answer youve already been given: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041779/how-to-use-jquery-to-prevent-the-others-type